# Could Nashorn's `eval` function be used to also interpret bytecode?

Tags: java, nashorn

If Nashorn had it's own sort of JRE that could only interpret bytecode compiled from JavaScript, would it be possible to place Java/Nashorn bytecode directly into the page so that Nashorn's JRE could execute that bytecode directly instead of first compiling it?

Answer (score 0):

You need do this function yourself. But why you need it? After first compile, Nashorn cache this code and next time don't translate that code, only evaluate.

Comment: In order to compete with [NaCL](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) it would be good to have a Java option that is architecture independent for projects that need to be implemented very quickly